# MCMC sampling using emcee is running extremely slow on intel xeon phi processor

Tags: performance, multiprocessing, slowdown, xeon-phi, emcee

So, I have the following code for MCMC for the parameters of a Gaussian process

code:

```
    walkers = 250
    pos_min = np.concatenate((np.array([self.initial_scale, self.initial_noise]), np.zeros(self.ndim)))
    pos_max = np.concatenate((np.array([self.initial_scale, self.initial_noise]), 2.0*np.ones(self.ndim)))


    psize = pos_max - pos_min
    pos = [pos_min + psize*np.random.rand(self.ndim+2) for i in range(nwalkers)]
    with Pool(4) as pool:
      sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, self.ndim+2, self.lnprob, pool=pool)
      pos, prob, state = sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 200)
      sampler.reset()
      sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 300)
    samples = sampler.flatchain[-500:,:]
    return samples
```

The function is self.lnprob is defined in the following code segment

code

```
   def lnprior(theta):
      l = theta[2:]
      s2_f = theta[0]
      s2_n = theta[1]
      if 0 < s2_f  and 0 < s2_n  and (l > 0).all() and (l < 2.0).all():
        return np.log(np.log(1 + (0.1/s2_n)**2)) -0.5*(np.log(np.sqrt(s2_f))/1.0)**2 
      return -np.inf

    def lnlike(theta):
      l = theta[2:]
      sigma_f = theta[0]
      sigman  = theta[1]
      self.kernel.k1.k1.constant_value = sigma_f
      self.kernel.k1.k2.length_scale = l
      self.kernel.k2.noise_level = sigman

      K = self.kernel(self.Xi)

      K[np.diag_indices_from(K)] += self.alpha

      L = cholesky(K, lower=True)  # Line 2


      # Support multi-dimensional output of self.y_train_
      y_train = self.Yi
      if y_train.ndim == 1:
        y_train = y_train[:, np.newaxis]

      alpha = cho_solve((L, True), y_train)  # Line 3

      # Compute log-likelihood (compare line 7)
      log_likelihood_dims = -0.5 * np.einsum("ik,ik->k", y_train, alpha)
      log_likelihood_dims -= np.log(np.diag(L)).sum()
      log_likelihood_dims -= K.shape[0] / 2 * np.log(2 * np.pi)
      log_likelihood = log_likelihood_dims.sum(-1)
      return log_likelihood


    lp = lnprior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
      return -np.inf
    return lp + lnlike(theta)
```

The code takes takes 30s on my laptop ( which is intel core i5 7th generation) . The size of theta array is 4 and size of Self.Xi is 2.

The same code takes over 400s on an intel xeon phi processor with 64 cores.

Also, I noticed as I increases number of the number of pools in multiprocessing pool the time seems to increase.

Is there any reason why it takes so much time on the intel xeon phi processor? What can I do it to speed it up on the intel xeon phi processor?

Comment: Do you increase the number of threads in the threadpool to reflect the increase in cores?

Comment: Ok, so if I tried with 16 , 32 and 8 pools in the multiprocessing  pool when running it on xeon phi. What I noticed that time is increasing with more processes in the pool. Also, I tried using the pool(). When there is no number inside the pool function it automatically selects the number of cores in the machine as the number of pools. The code was then even slower.